# Not Reading text from a .txt file which is present on server

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not Reading text from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931043/not-reading-text-from-server)

i am trying to read text from a .txt file which is present on server but my code is not reading text from file i am using android version 2.1 , will you please also tell me how can i handle the exception in order to caught the error.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv= new TextView(this);
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();


    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://linktomywebsite/textfile.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(str +"\n");
            tv.setText(content);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e){
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


};
```

Comment: You should post your logcat error logs so we can help you figure out what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextView tv= new TextView(this);
```

This creates a new TextView that is independent of your current visible layout.

You are not putting this newly created TextView in your layout anywhere so your result, which is contained within that TextView, will not be shown

Assuming your code works to retrieve the text from your site (it looks fine to me) this is likely why you aren't seeing any results.

Try calling

```
setContentView(tv);
```

after your `try { } catch { }` and see if that works

Comment: Just adding to that, if you're trying to add it to a TextView that you already have in your layout, change TextView tv= new TextView(this); to TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewName); otherwise make a reference to your layout and then call yourLayout.addView(tv);

Comment: well after replacing TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewName); , it is still not showing any text from server.

Answer (score 0):

You must link your existing TextView in the main Layout

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.myTextView);
```