# Not Reading text from server

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to read all the text from server, I think that my code is not retrieving text from server will you please help me how can I fix this problem, I am new to android development. Thanks in advance

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text);


                try {

                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com:80/");
                    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                    // read text returned by server

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        content.append(line +"\n");
                    }
                    tv.setText(content.toString());
                    setContentView(tv);

                    in.close();
                }

                catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                    System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());

                }

                catch (IOException e) {

                    System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());

                }


};        


}
```

Comment: Try the code given in this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094529/android-read-contents-of-a-url-content-missing-after-in-result

Answer (score 0):

Take these lines

```
tv.setText(line);
setContentView(tv);
```

out of while loop

Use StringBuilder object (declared before loop) in while loop and append the strings in that.
After while loop take string from StringBuilder and do tv.setText(string)

Comment: i have edited my code , but it is still not working , how can i check is it reading text from server ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try like this, just a thought only :

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                // read text returned by server
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://www.google.com:80/").openConnection().getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line +"\n");
                }

tv.setText(content.toString());
setContentView(tv);
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply ,i have edited my code above please have a look , its still not working

Comment: still not working , is there any IDE setting which allow to read text from url.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Please paste your error  if any